# Forcing a Redis snapshot / persistence vis SAVE command?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using the ioredis library for Node.js - I am wondering how to send Redis a signal to force persistence. I am having a hard time finding out how to do this. The SAVE command seems to do this, but I can't verify that. Can anyone tell me for sure if the SAVE command will tell Redis to write everything in memory to disk on command?

> this article hints at it:
>   https://community.nodebb.org/topic/932/redis-useful-info so does this
>   one: http://redis.io/commands/save

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, `SAVE` will do the job for you, but it has a synchronous behaviour, means it will be blocking till the saving is done not letting other clients retrieve data. as shown in the docs:

> You almost never want to call SAVE in production environments where it
>   will block all the other clients

The better solution is described in [`BGSAVE`](http://redis.io/commands/bgsave) , you can call `BGSAVE` and then check for the command `LASTSAVE` which will return for you the timestamp of the latest snapshot taken from the instance. http://redis.io/commands/lastsave

Comment: So is `redis-cli SAVE` before a server reboot the solution to persistence then? Like `redis-cli SAVE && reboot` would be as fine as a reboot without concerns about redis persistence?